# Parse.com includeKey with PFFile

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

Is there any way to get the data from a Class that has a PFFile pointer (photo)?

```
let query = PFObject(classname: "Person")
query.includeKey("photo")

[Error]: field photo cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object
```

So i don't have to do another request to parse.com after finishing the first request?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of includeKey is that you download the pointer column as well, so it should work. Are you sure that the "photo" column is a pointer column? Or Misspelled name?

Comment: Yes, im sure, this is an example i made now: https://gist.github.com/ivangodfather/3084b374366f6624ee5c

Comment: http://www.ruiznadal.com/screenshots/usertable.png <- the actual PFUser table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PFFile` reference isn't the same as a pointer, it's an explicit reference to the file. A pointer is a reference to an object in the Parse data store (a reference to the object id). `includeKey` can only be used to get additional objects in the response, not raw file data.

After you get your `Person` you will then need to get the `PFFile` and then make a request to get the file data (using one of the methods like `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:`).

Comment: So i need to chain both requests, after getting the Person then do another request to get the data? This is very annoying cause can be slow...

Comment: There isn't really another way it could work because the PFFile object returned has no way to actually hold the data (and changing the API to do that would likely cause several other issues). If you did absolutely require some functionality like that then you would need to use cloud code.